# receive json content from node.js into html using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

I have this functionality where I want to send an AJAX request to the server and receive output of MySQL query on http://localhost:3000/result.html page. This happens on the click of a button.

```
<body>

<form action="/setLocation" method="POST">
  ...
<button id="get">Do Action</button>

</form>

<script>

   document.getElementById('get').onclick = function(){

   calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

   $.ajax({

    url: 'https://localhost:3000/setLocation',

    type:'POST',

    success : function(data){

    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log('data received ',data); 

    val = document.getElementById('driver_details').innerHTML;

   }

 }); 

}

</script>

</body>
```

and in my server.js, I am handling this in the following way:

```
const express = require("express");

var app = express();

const mySqlConnection = require("./connection");


app.post('/setLocation', function(req, res){

  r_value = between(0,7)

  value = '';

  console.log(req.body);

  mySqlConnection.query("SELECT first_name from tableX where id = ?",r_value,function  (err,result) {

    if (err) throw err;

    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));

  });

});
```

I am getting the json response but on http://localhost:3000/setLocation page and not on my http://localhost:3000/result.html page. How can I receive the response on the same page from where I sent the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "trick" from HTML... Any button in a `<form>` will act like a submit button (event without `type="submit"` attribute). You need to add a `event.preventDefault()` in your click handler. In other words change

```
document.getElementById('get').onclick = function(){
```

by

```
document.getElementById('get').onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // code continue here
```

Comment: Happy to hear, may I kindly ask you to accept the answer, I'll appreciate it very much (and also it may help others)